# Slowness on my code while looping through rows

Tags: excel, vba

```
Set WB = Thisworkbook
Set wk = WB.Sheets("Final")
Set ws = WB.Sheets("OIT-Temp")

irow = wk.Range("B65000").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row

For i = 2 To irow Step 1
If not wk.Cells(i, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "#N/A" Then
wk.cells(i, 2).copy ws.Cells(i, 2)
wk.cells(i,3).Value = 128

Else

wk.Cells(i, 3).Value = 198

End if
Next i
```

I'm here facing too much of lag while running this code and unable to understand what's wrong with my code

Comment: Try: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and after the loop `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`

Comment: Looping Worksheet cells is slow.  You will want to load it all up in variant arrays and loop those.  Then bulk assign back from a variant array to the sheet.  Every time you reference the worksheet it slows down.  This little bit is barely noticeable in a small dataset, but in a large one can be very noticeable.

Comment: Hello Scott, Can you please help me load it in varient arrays? Please help me with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next adapted code. It uses arrays, mostly working in memory and drops the processed arrays at once. That's why it should be very fast:

```
Sub speedUpCode()
 Dim WB As Workbook, wk As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, iRow As Long, arr, arrCopy, i As Long
 
 Set WB = ThisWorkbook
 Set wk = WB.Sheets("Final")
 Set ws = WB.Sheets("OIT-Temp")

 iRow = wk.Range("B" & wk.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'Find last row
 arr = wk.Range("B2:C" & iRow).Value2      'place the range in an array for faster iteration
 arrCopy = ws.Range("B2:B" & iRow).Value2  'place the range in an array for faster iteration

 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If Not CStr(arr(i, 1)) = "Error 2042" Then ''#N/A
        arrCopy(i, 1) = arr(i, 1)
        arr(i, 2) = 128
    Else
        arr(i, 2) = 198
    End If
 Next i
 'drop the processed array values:
 wk.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(arr), 2).Value2 = arr
 ws.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(arrCopy), 1).Value2 = arrCopy
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Some general points:

1. Indent your code.
2. Give your variables meaningful names.
3. Normal to write positive code block in if/else first.
4. I'm not sure how you're doing an `xlUp` on an entire row.

For this specific problem, reading and writing cells is computationally expensive. You can remove a lot of this by reading and writing data in bulk and working with your data in arrays in memory.

Try this and see if it speeds things up.

```vb
Sub FastReadWrite()
'   Set the range references.
    With ThisWorkbook
        With .Sheets("Final")
            Dim maxRow As Long
            maxRow = .Range("B65000").End(xlUp).Row
            
            Dim finalData As Range
            Set finalData = .Range("B2:C" & maxRow)
        End With
        Dim oitTemData As Range
        Set oitTemData = .Sheets("OIT-Temp") _
                         .Range("B2:C" & maxRow)
    End With
        
'   Read the data from the ranges into memory.
    Dim fArray() As Variant: fArray = finalData.Formula2R1C1
    Dim tArray() As Variant: tArray = oitTemData.Formula2R1C1
        
'   Main logic loop.
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(fArray, 1)
        If fArray(i, 1) = "#N/A" Then
            fArray(i, 2) = 198
        Else
            tArray(i, 1) = fArray(i, 1)
            fArray(i, 2) = 128
        End If
    Next i
    
'   Write the data to the ranges.
    finalData.Formula2R1C1 = fArray
    oitTemData.Formula2R1C1 = tArray
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a ton is a small gratitude for your help and fixing the problem here. It really worked so fast, I couldn't even notice that my file is ready. :)

Comment: @ShreeshaHegde you're welcome - working with arrays in memory can be a bit more fiddly but it's definitely worth the effort. If you could accept this as the answer then it may help others who come across it.